# EC2 AMI became Ubuntu and the yum command became unavailable on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

Last week I've created an AWS Instance using the Ubuntu Server 20.x AMI. It had `yum` built-in. Today I've deleted that instance and created a new Instance using the same AMI. After I've launched the Instance I've noticed the welcome screen was substantially different and the default (the AWS given) user name was different too. The UN on previous Instance was `ec2-user` whereas in this Instance it is `ubuntu` After I logged in over `ssh` and typed `yum` it said `Command 'yum' not found`

**Question**:
I'd like to create the same type Instance which I created last week. How can I do it?

Here are the Screenshots of the welcome screens of the previous and the current Instances.

**EC2** (In this screenshot when I took it the root user was seen. It had `ec2-user`as default)
[image]

**Ubuntu**
[image]

Comment: Your first screenshot and description is amazon linux 2. The second is Ubuntu. You were using Amazon Linux 2 originally.

Answer (score 0):

As `jordanm` correctly put it, I was selecting the `Ubuntu` and not the `Amazon Linux 2` AMI. I just oversaw the `Amazon Linux 2` standing on the top of the  AMIs list.